# Can an Excel UDF trigger a macro or worksheet event?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, macros

I’m working on an interactive Excel chart where all you have to do is mouse over selected cells to update the chart using a UDF.  This works fine,
however the chart data does not always come on consecutive lines and I would like to use the Excel filter to hide those rows, removing them from the chart.

I have the VBA code to hide the rows and I’ve tried:

- inserting the VBA code into the UDF
- calling a separate macro from the UDF
- creating a worksheet change event (based on the cell the UDF
  actually changes), but it doesn't trigger when the UDF changes the
  value.

Is there a way that that a UDF can trigger either a macro or worksheet change event?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example using a *Global* Boolean flag called `DoIt`:

- when the UDF `whatever()` want the sub `hello()` called, it sets `DoIt` to **True**
- the Calculate event is raised and sees the `DoIt` is **True**
- the Calculate event macro sets `DoIt` to **False** and calls `hello()`

In the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If DoIt Then
        DoIt = False
        Call hello
    End If
End Sub
```

In a standard module:

```
Public DoIt As Boolean

Public Function whatever(r As Range) As String
    whatever = ""
    If r.Value <> "" Then
        whatever = r.Text
        DoIt = True
    End If
End Function

Public Sub hello()
    MsgBox "HELLO"
End Sub
```

Comment: @aquixano  Make sure your `hello()` activates or selects the correct worksheet ??

Comment: ’s StudentSomething is still not working.  I modified your Public Sub Hello adding the two AutoFilter lines:      Public Sub hello()
    MsgBox "HELLO"
    Sheets("Grahp").Range("valSelOption").AutoFilter Field:=8
    Sheets("Grahp").Range("valSelOption").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
I get the Hello msbox, but the macro doesn’t filter the column.  The lines work in a standalone macro.  I triggered the whatever function:  =whatever(valSelOption)  Thoughts?

Comment: It does.  I tested that by changing the value of D1 on desired sheet to 20 (I removed that code after see it worked before posting)It does.  I tested that by changing the value of D1 on desired sheet to 20 (I removed that code after see it worked before posting)

Comment: @aquixano  very strange..............if you can change a cell, you should be able to manipulate the filter...................what happens if you have `hello()` call your standalone ??

Comment: same result.  IF I put the cursor in the cell with the =whatever(valSelOption) function and hit the enter key it works, but still not by triggering the UDF alone.

Comment: Found a solution!  How do I mark this question closed/solved?