# VBA Passing arguments from function to sub

Tags: excel, vba

In *VBA* I have writen a *sub*, that for the purpose of the question does the following:

1. Creates a new worksheet named by the user
2. Extracts data from a database determined by *two* of the input values from the user
3. Places that data ordered in the new worksheet (1)

The functionality I wish to achieve is for the user to be able to input *three* variables through a UDF right from an Excel sheet, as shown below:

[Description of how the user should interface with the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuacE.png)

In order to achieve this specific method of user interface it seems that I need to use a *function* as a *macro*;

```
Function Do_Stuff_With_Theese_Imputs(x, y, z)
Call Do_Stuff(x, y, z)
End Function

Sub Do_Stuff(x, y, z)
'Code that makes the new sheet by the name "z"(argument from the function) here:
'Code for database handeling by the variables "x" & "y"(arguments from the function) here:
'Etc...
End sub
```

I might be trying to solve this problem in an unnecessarily complicated manner, so I'm wide open to suggestions for other implementations as long as the *UI* remains the same with regards to the user. Otherwise, I need some help on how to pass the arguments *x, y and z* from the *function* to the *sub*.

**EDIT:**
Due to my unclear line of questioning this has become a point of confusion:

It is a user defined *requirement* that the UDF (Which I want to use as a macro) be accessible from *any* Exel sheet on which computer this UDF has been 'installed. It should from the users point of view be applicable just like the classic `=SUM` function.

**EDIT 2:**
Once again to be clear, it should be accessible from any Excel sheet whithout allways having to pe present (in the form of a `button`, `extra sheet` or `form`) upon opening a sheet.

It has come to my attention that this just might not be possible to achieve.

Comment: A UDF is invoked by Excel's calculation engine when it recalculates the cells: a UDF isn't allowed to do things that affect any other cells, or affect global/application state. You need a macro, not a UDF.

Comment: You _cannot_ use a cell formula to change anything else other than the cells the formula applies to. Have you considered a `Form` for `UI` where the user inputs the information needed?

Comment: What would trigger the code to generate a new sheet? What you are trying to do would result in a new worksheet everytime the sheet recalculates (**if it was allowed the way you tried**).

Comment: I should have made that point a bit more clear, it's a user defined _requirement_ to be able to use the UDF (which I want to work like a macro) in this spesific way. Now that I know it's not possible, I simply have to deliver that result to the user and try to implement a `Form` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Consider using `Worksheet_Change`, so that when the user changes any of the cells you can fire off `Do_Stuff` using the values from those cells as arguments.

You can use `Intersect` to limit your actions to those cells. You biggest challenge here is to determine when the user has finished entering the correct data- after all they can only fill in one cell at a time (which is a problem you originally had).

**Option 2:** Instead of `Worksheet_Change` you can add a button to the sheet next to the cells. A trick here is to enable the button based on valid values in the cells. The user can then click the button when they have finished - the button will call `Do_Stuff` using the values from those cells as arguments.

The above two options do not require you to change `Do_Stuff`, they only impact on how you call `Do_Stuff`.

Comment: I found that an `ActiveX` button works better than a form button for scenarios like this. Visually sometimes a label with hyperlink like formatting (blue & underline) works too.

Comment: I think I can sell your suggestion _Option 2_ to the end user, however this requires them to open a spesific Excel sheet where the implementation is stored. Ideally this UDF(in reality a macro) should be accesable in _any_ Excel sheet where the UDF has been 'installed. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: When you install the UDF, also install the button? Or even a tailored ribbon button or menu item?

Comment: A menu item might be possible, although I _really_ want it to behave like a UDF

Comment: @RA94: Your biggest issue with a UDF is how often it will fire - often with unintended consequences. The UDF will fire every time one of the input cells changes, so you will end up with files in all sorts of strange places. And if you recalculate (full) or you make it volatile, then it will fire even more often. How many new sheets do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this these ways, preferably the second:

```
Sub Do_Stuff()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As String

With Worksheets(1)  'It takes the values from the first sheet, you can specify the sheet by a name
                    ' With Worksheets("NAME")

    x = .Cells(2, 2).Value
    y = .Cells(2, 3).Value
    z = .Cells(2, 4).Value

End With

'Code that makes the new sheet by the name "z"(argument from the function) here:
'Code for database handeling by the variables "x" & "y"(arguments from the function) here:
'Etc...
End Sub
```

Or this:

```
Sub Do_Stuff()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As String

x = Application.InputBox("Write a number", "Get Number", , , , , , 1)
y = Application.InputBox("Write a number", "Get Number", , , , , , 1)
z = Application.InputBox("Write a new sheet name", "Get a new sheet name", , , , , , 2)


'Code that makes the new sheet by the name "z"(argument from the function) here:
'Code for database handeling by the variables "x" & "y"(arguments from the function) here:
'Etc...
End Sub
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see clairly now that I'm answering these replies that I have failed to be clair enough in my line of questioning. These suggestions would absolutely work, however it requires a different use case from the user which means I can't apply them. I might be trying to solve the unsolvable but always open to suggestions.

Comment: What is exactly that vital that has to remain the same? I can't see anything that maybe after slight changes or something small added could be problematic with similar approach to the first code. If those cells where the values are have to be dynamic that couldn't be a problem.

Comment: I will probably update my initial question to contain this too, since it seems to cause some confusion.

As defined by the user; From _any_ Excel sheet (on which computer this UDF has been 'installed with Excel), a UDF should be able to be called, much like the `=SUM` function. So any suggestion that requires the use of a spesific Excel sheet (for example; use of a `button`, `form`, etc..) would not give the user experiance I wish to deliver. I do understand that what I'm trying to achieve might not be possible, but in that case it just can't be helped.

Answer (score 0):

## This is a terrible idea

Monitor cell `E5` for changes. When a change is detected, trigger your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
        Call Do_Stuff([B2], [C2], [D2])
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of monitoring a single cell, could you make the `sub Worksheet_Change` monitor and fire from changing something within the function. For instance;

    `Public Function Do_Stuff_With_Theese_Imputs(x, y, z)`
        `Bolean_Var = true`
    `End Function`

    `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
        `If Bolean_Var = True Then`
            `Bolean_Var = False`
            `Call Do_Stuff(x, y, z)`
        `End If`
    `End Sub`

Comment: @RA94 - you mean to use a global variable as a flag. But what would trigger the flag? That is the million dollar question. A UDF cannot change a global variable I think.

Comment: Yes, that's essentialy what I want to achieve, too bad it does not seem to be a valid solution. I got my hopes up when reading this;
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119689/can-an-excel-udf-trigger-a-macro-or-worksheet-event)
One last theory to throw out there; Could you use a UDF to collect the information, merge it all into a single string and paste that back to the original cell, then have a macro fire from a change made by that certain UDF, so the macro would get it's info from the Excel cell and not the UDF

Comment: @RA94 - I did a little testing and a UDF can write into a global, but that brought Excel into an unstable state ("Out of stack" error) and it crashed eventually.